# Store and recover a set of words in a char array

Tags: c++, string

I have a vector of words which holds some words.

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
```

These words are concatenated into an array of chars called features (after each word a null character (\0) is inserted into the array):

```
while (j < i - offset){
    logger.message("j: " + toString(j) );
    std::strcat(features,words.at(j).c_str());
    std::strcat(features,"\0");
    logger.message("std::strcat(features,words.at(j).c_str())");
    j++;
}
```

After that I want to recover each of the words, but the following code prints all the words concatenated (it does not divides the words by the inserted null character \0).

```
char * features_ptr = features;

    while(*features_ptr){
        std::string Str = std::string(features_ptr);
        logger.message( "palavra: " + Str);
     features_ptr += strlen(features) + 1;
    }
```

What should I do to get the strings word by word?

Comment: `std::strcat(features,"\0");` strcat doesn't work this way. You cannot use strcat or other str\* C functions to manipulate strings with embedded \0s.

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: If you are programming in C++, prefer to use `std::string` rather than character arrays.  You don't need the `str*()` functions when using `std::string`.

Comment: @skeller there is a list of caveats for `strtok` that are not mentioned by cplusplus.com. Recommend it with caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::strcat` will not add `\0` delimiter because it operates on c-string and `\0` is considered an empty string, so your `features` will be one string spliced together from all the words. If you treat it as array of `char`s then you can insert your `\0`. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and whatever it is it doesn't look the right way of doing it, but for the sake of an exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char features[20];
    std::vector<std::string> words = { "123","456","789" };

    int i = 0;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < words.size(); ++n)
    {
        for (size_t m = 0; m < words[n].size(); ++m)
            features[i++] = words[n][m];
        features[i++] = 0;
    }
    features[i] = 0; //<-- extra terminating null

    char *features_ptr = features;
    while (*features_ptr)
    {
        std::cout << features_ptr << std::endl;
        features_ptr += std::strlen(features_ptr) + 1;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/GoVlRl

```
123
456
789
```

Please note one **important** detail about this approach, additional `features[i] = 0;` after the `for` loop which adds second terminating null `\0` at the end of your spliced string. This is essential if you want your `while (*features_ptr)` loop to stop at the end of the string.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned `C++11` tag.
When giving answers in C++11 or above, it would be good, if you mention the same in the answers. A lot of new OP wouldn't be knowing how to compile a C++11 code. Better to mention flags such as `-std=c++11`

Comment: @badola The tag description is quite clear about the use of the tag "Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler. Use a version specific tag for questions related to a specific standard revision [C++11], [C++17], etc." The OP doesn't have a specific question about a particular C++11 feature, so they didn't use it.

Comment: you used `for (auto const &word : words) {...}`. The syntax would not compile without providing the compilation flag for C++11 or above. It was just constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2):

I see a problem on this line:

```
features_ptr += strlen(features) + 1;
```

I suspect you mean

```
features_ptr += strlen(features_ptr) + 1;
```

As others have said, strcat probably also doesn't do what you want exactly, either.

Answer (score 1):

C character array is considered as string till characters before NULL `\0`. If you use `\0` inside a string, the string will be terminated at that NULL only. So `"\0"` is as good as an empty string.

Your problem is standard serialization and deserialization of array of strings. Instead of using `\0` as delimiter, you can use some other character which is not present in the strings such as `~`. However, if there is no such character available, you need to append more information in the serialized string to assist deserialization later. One such way is as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-array-string/).